# Get all data from indexed db and insert into server side using post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, indexeddb

I have a indexed db which will have some data in it. I am getting those data and wanted to push those data over server side.

***Step 1* : Get those data**

```
   var transaction = db.transaction(["customer"], "readonly");  
   var obj = transaction.objectStore("customer");
   var cursorRequest = obj.openCursor();


   cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(evt) {                    
    var cursor = evt.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
        cust_ids.push(cursor.value);
        cursor.continue();
    }
  };
```

Above will give me whatever data is there in the IDB. Now, I will iterate those records so I can insert it into server side database.

***Step 2 :***
**Loop through**

```
for (var i=0; i < cust_ids.length;i++){
   customers += JSON.stringify(cust_ids[i]);       
  }
  console.log("from cust" + customers);
```

***Step 3 :***
**Ajax Call :**
Now, we will make a ajax call which will push those data over server side using post method.

```
  $.ajax({
  url: 'myurl',
   type: 'POST',
  data:customers,//here it only push one record to server though i have       whole data in above console.
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
 // async: false,
  success: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
  });
```

The issue what ever i do it only inserts first record.I am able to get all the data but not able to push all the data into sever side database.

***Json String :***

```
{"cmp_id":131,"cust_id":131,"name":"pranav","zip":"6979","mobile":"9749797","email":"efe@gmail.com","birth_date":"2016-11-10T05:00:00Z"}    {"cust_id":10001,"name":"Edward Logan","add1":"1 Harborside Drive","city":"Flushing","state":"New York","country":"USA","zip":"380061","mobile":"9974682025","email":"edward.logan@email.com","gender":"MALE","bod":"1985-12-31T05:00:00Z","anv_date":"2012-11-20T05:00:00Z"}{"cust_id":10002,"name":"Barry Hoppe","add1":"45020 Aviation Drive","city":"Sterling","state":"Virginia","country":"USA","zip":"20166","mobile":"9033640098","phone":"7035558967","email":"john.dulles@email.com","gender":"MALE","bod":"1981-06-30T04:00:00Z","anv_date":"2011-10-26T04:00:00Z"}{"cust_id":10003,"name":"Albert Lambert","add1":"10000 West OHare","city":"Chicago","state":"Illinois","country":"USA","zip":"60666","mobile":"9724263068","email":"albert.lambert@email.com","gender":"MALE","bod":"1988-07-05T04:00:00Z"}{"cust_id":10004,"name":"Oscar Higgins","add1":"Hangar Center","city":"Brooklyn","state":"New York","country":"USA","zip":"11371","mobile":"8401111085","email":"oscar.higgins@email.com","gender":"MALE","bod":"1990-12-09T05:00:00Z"}{"cust_id":10005,"name":"John Smith","add1":"6000 North Terminal Parkway","city":"Atlanta","state":"Georgia","country":"USA","zip":"30320","mobile":"9574323013","email":"john.smith@email.com","gender":"MALE","bod":"1985-09-24T04:00:00Z"}
```

Comment: The first step is to find out where in the sequence of event the subsequent rows are getting lost. Are you sure the original load loop is getting all the customers? If so is the severside URL configured to accept more than one customer? You can also use developer tools in Chrome to view the uploaded json string - does it have all the customers? Is it valid Json? You can put a debut statement in the server side method to see what it's getting and how many rows it's getting or iterating over.

Comment: yes i have added the Json string which will be sent using post method please check in question above it is added as it shown in DOM(Copy paste)

Comment: Ok, so now to the server side. How does it work? Can you dump the json received? Does it convert the Json string to an array object? Does it iterate over each row? If so, can you print out between each read and write?  or does it insert it as a chunk? Can you display the sql generated for the insert? etc.

Comment: Yes over we need to just mention application/json and thats it ,will be handed that side.
Issue is i am not able to push it from here it just push one row.

Comment: If you're sure it's not the server side, then open developer tools in chrome, go to network, and drill down into the contents of the post  and check that the whole json string is being upload. Also, dump the json string into a json parser and make sure it's valid json. I think if it's an array it needs to have brackets surrounding it "[", "]".

Comment: give me 5 mints i will share docs here i am testing it

Comment: please check : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CuUjkKOFdzUu8zkW66cyMvrcpGuogice1vMF-Ldk_bs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

From your json post, it doesn't look like you're creating an array, just a series of single json objects delimited by a comma. You need to create it as an array. Here's an example of a json array:

```
[
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        color: "yellow",
        value: "#ff0"
    },
    {
        color: "black",
        value: "#000"
    }
]
```

Edit: one possibility is to append the brackets at the beginning and the end:

```
  var customers = "["; 

  for (var i=0; i < cust_ids.length;i++){ 
          customers += JSON.stringify(cust_ids[i]);
  } 
  customers += "]";
```

Comment: testing it lemme get back to you

Comment: it went into dead lock

Comment: Dump the json into a json parser on the web and see if it's valid. Google creating a json array in javascript.